# AVQueuePlayer plays audio only once from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, audio, avqueueplayer

I have array of QueuePlayer as below,

```
Print Queue Player array : (
    "<AVQueuePlayer: 0x7fed625a51c0>",
    "<AVQueuePlayer: 0x7fed624baa00>",
    "<AVQueuePlayer: 0x7fed624c43c0>"
)
```

On button click I am playing audio from above array,

```
-(IBAction)click_Play:(UIButton *)sender {

    [(AVQueuePlayer *)[arrQueuePlayer objectAtIndex:sender.tag] setVolume:1.0];
    [(AVQueuePlayer *)[arrQueuePlayer objectAtIndex:sender.tag] play];
}
```

Reason behind generating array of QueuePlayer is, my play button is in UITableView. Playing audio from array on button click works well only for the first time. If I click play button again. It's not playing sound. Don't know what is wrong. I checked it by debugging code, My array is getting nulled or anything. Then why it is not playing again on button click?

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you allow to play complete track and after that to try to play again?

Comment: @Tirth Yess I tried to play it again after playing complete track once.

Comment: how you add tracks in AVQueuePlayer?

Comment: @Tirth That is quite large logic. As I have audio tracks added locally. User allowed to select as many audio tracks as they want. Then after I sequentially added all audio tracks in QueuePlayer and generated this array for UITableView.
But I am wondering, If it plays sound first time from the array then why not again?

Comment: Your problem come from other code but not you given code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are playing queue player from array, there may be possibilities that it becomes nil after playing once. I am not sure whether this your actual issue or not. Because I don’t have any idea how you have created these queue player objects and added it in array. But I guess queue player object gets nil after playing should be the issue.

If so then for that you have to recreate your queue player once it is getting played. As `AVQueuePlayer` don’t have any delegate method such as `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:`(This is the delegate method of `AVAudioPlayer`). So for `AVQueuePlayer` you need to add observer for `playerItemDidReachEnd:` as below,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:item];
```

In this observer method recreate your queue player and replace it in your array. Hope it will help you out! Cheers..